# could not configure talloc

Tags: c, memory-management, cygwin

While trying to run `configure` configure [talloc](https://talloc.samba.org/talloc/doc/html/index.html) I am getting this output in console

```
Checking for program gcc or cc           : C:\cygwin\bin\gcc.exe
Checking for program cpp                 : C:\cygwin\bin\cpp.exe
Checking for program ar                  : C:\cygwin\bin\ar.exe
Checking for program ranlib              : C:\cygwin\bin\ranlib.exe
Checking for gcc                         : ok
Checking for program git                 : C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe
Check for -MD                            : yes
Checking for program gdb                 : C:\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe
Checking build system                    : CYGWIN_NT-6.1 NET001D162 2.3.1(0.291/5/3) 2015-11-14 12:44 x86_64 Cygwin
Checking for header sys/utsname.h        : no
Checking uname sysname type              : not found
Checking uname machine type              : not found
Checking uname release type              : not found
Checking uname version type              : not found
Checking for header stdio.h              : no
Checking simple C program                : C:\cygwin\home\mohammad.faisal\talloc-2.1.5\lib\replace\..\..\buildtools\wafsamba\wscript:310: error: the configuration failed (see 'C:\\cygwin\\home\\mohammad.faisal\\talloc-2.1.5\\bin\\config.log')
```

and the `config.log` says:

```
# project talloc (2.1.5) configured on Tue Jan 19 05:50:51 2016 by
# waf 1.5.19 (abi 7, python 2070bf0 on win32)
# using ./buildtools/bin/waf configure
#

----------------------------------------
Checking for program gcc or cc
  find program=['gcc', 'cc'] paths=[] var='CC'
  -> 'C:\\cygwin\\bin\\gcc.exe'

----------------------------------------
Checking for program cpp
  find program=['cpp'] paths=[] var='CPP'
  -> 'C:\\cygwin\\bin\\cpp.exe'

----------------------------------------
Checking for program ar
  find program=['ar'] paths=[] var='AR'
  -> 'C:\\cygwin\\bin\\ar.exe'

----------------------------------------
Checking for program ranlib
  find program=['ranlib'] paths=[] var='RANLIB'
  -> 'C:\\cygwin\\bin\\ranlib.exe'

----------------------------------------
Checking for gcc 
ok 

----------------------------------------
Checking for program git
  find program=['git'] paths=[] var='GIT'
  -> 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\cmd\\git.exe'

----------------------------------------
Check for -MD
==>
int main() {return 0;}

<==
[1/1] Compiling [32m..\test.c[0m
['C:\\cygwin\\bin\\gcc.exe', '-MD', '..\\test.c', '-c', '-o', 'C:\\cygwin\\home\\mohammad.faisal\\talloc-2.1.5\\bin\\.conf_check_0\\testbuild\\default\\test_1.o']
yes

----------------------------------------
Checking for program gdb
  find program=['gdb'] paths=[] var=None
  -> 'C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe'

----------------------------------------
Checking build system
CYGWIN_NT-6.1 NET001D162 2.3.1(0.291/5/3) 2015-11-14 12:44 x86_64 Cygwin

----------------------------------------
Checking for header sys/utsname.h
==>
#include <sys/utsname.h>

int main(void) { return 0; }
<==
[1/1] Compiling [32m..\test.c[0m
['C:\\cygwin\\bin\\gcc.exe', '-MD', '..\\test.c', '-c', '-o', 'default\\test_1.o']
command returned "Build failed: local variable 'node' referenced before assignment"no

----------------------------------------
Checking uname sysname type
==>
#define BUILD_SYSTEM "CYGWIN_NT-6.1 NET001D162 2.3.1(0.291/5/3) 2015-11-14 12:44 x86_64 Cygwin"

 int main(void) { 
                               struct utsname n;
                               if (uname(&n) == -1) return -1;
                               printf("%s", n.sysname);
                               ; return 0; }

<==
[1/2] Compiling [32m..\test.c[0m
..\test.c: In function ‘main’:
..\test.c:4:47: error: storage size of ‘n’ isn’t known
                                struct utsname n;
                                               ^
..\test.c:6:32: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
                                printf("%s", n.sysname);
                                ^
['C:\\cygwin\\bin\\gcc.exe', '-MD', '-Idefault', '-I..', '-Idefault', '-I..', '..\\test.c', '-c', '-o', 'default\\test_1.o']
command returned 'Build failed:  -> task failed (err #1): \n\t{task: cc test.c -> test_1.o}'not found

----------------------------------------
Checking uname machine type
==>
#define BUILD_SYSTEM "CYGWIN_NT-6.1 NET001D162 2.3.1(0.291/5/3) 2015-11-14 12:44 x86_64 Cygwin"
/* #undef SYSTEM_UNAME_SYSNAME */

 int main(void) { 
                               struct utsname n;
                               if (uname(&n) == -1) return -1;
                               printf("%s", n.machine);
                               ; return 0; }

<==
[1/2] Compiling [32m..\test.c[0m
..\test.c: In function ‘main’:
..\test.c:5:47: error: storage size of ‘n’ isn’t known
                                struct utsname n;
                                               ^
..\test.c:7:32: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
                                printf("%s", n.machine);
                                ^
['C:\\cygwin\\bin\\gcc.exe', '-MD', '-Idefault', '-I..', '-Idefault', '-I..', '..\\test.c', '-c', '-o', 'default\\test_1.o']
command returned 'Build failed:  -> task failed (err #1): \n\t{task: cc test.c -> test_1.o}'not found

----------------------------------------
Checking uname release type
==>
#define BUILD_SYSTEM "CYGWIN_NT-6.1 NET001D162 2.3.1(0.291/5/3) 2015-11-14 12:44 x86_64 Cygwin"
/* #undef SYSTEM_UNAME_SYSNAME */
/* #undef SYSTEM_UNAME_MACHINE */

 int main(void) { 
                               struct utsname n;
                               if (uname(&n) == -1) return -1;
                               printf("%s", n.release);
                               ; return 0; }

<==
[1/2] Compiling [32m..\test.c[0m
..\test.c: In function ‘main’:
..\test.c:6:47: error: storage size of ‘n’ isn’t known
                                struct utsname n;
                                               ^
..\test.c:8:32: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
                                printf("%s", n.release);
                                ^
['C:\\cygwin\\bin\\gcc.exe', '-MD', '-Idefault', '-I..', '-Idefault', '-I..', '..\\test.c', '-c', '-o', 'default\\test_1.o']
command returned 'Build failed:  -> task failed (err #1): \n\t{task: cc test.c -> test_1.o}'not found

----------------------------------------
Checking uname version type
==>
#define BUILD_SYSTEM "CYGWIN_NT-6.1 NET001D162 2.3.1(0.291/5/3) 2015-11-14 12:44 x86_64 Cygwin"
/* #undef SYSTEM_UNAME_SYSNAME */
/* #undef SYSTEM_UNAME_MACHINE */
/* #undef SYSTEM_UNAME_RELEASE */

 int main(void) { 
                               struct utsname n;
                               if (uname(&n) == -1) return -1;
                               printf("%s", n.version);
                               ; return 0; }

<==
[1/2] Compiling [32m..\test.c[0m
..\test.c: In function ‘main’:
..\test.c:7:47: error: storage size of ‘n’ isn’t known
                                struct utsname n;
                                               ^
..\test.c:9:32: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
                                printf("%s", n.version);
                                ^
['C:\\cygwin\\bin\\gcc.exe', '-MD', '-Idefault', '-I..', '-Idefault', '-I..', '..\\test.c', '-c', '-o', 'default\\test_1.o']
command returned 'Build failed:  -> task failed (err #1): \n\t{task: cc test.c -> test_1.o}'not found

----------------------------------------
Checking for header stdio.h
==>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) { return 0; }
<==
[1/1] Compiling [32m..\test.c[0m
['C:\\cygwin\\bin\\gcc.exe', '-MD', '..\\test.c', '-c', '-o', 'default\\test_1.o']
command returned "Build failed: local variable 'node' referenced before assignment"no

----------------------------------------
Checking simple C program
==>
#define BUILD_SYSTEM "CYGWIN_NT-6.1 NET001D162 2.3.1(0.291/5/3) 2015-11-14 12:44 x86_64 Cygwin"
/* #undef SYSTEM_UNAME_SYSNAME */
/* #undef SYSTEM_UNAME_MACHINE */
/* #undef SYSTEM_UNAME_RELEASE */
/* #undef SYSTEM_UNAME_VERSION */

 int main(void) { printf("hello world"); return 0; }

<==
[1/2] Compiling [32m..\test.c[0m
..\test.c: In function ‘main’:
..\test.c:7:19: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
  int main(void) { printf("hello world"); return 0; }
                   ^
['C:\\cygwin\\bin\\gcc.exe', '-IC:\\cygwin\\home\\mohammad.faisal\\talloc-2.1.5\\lib\\replace\\..\\..\\buildtools\\wafsamba', '-MD', '-Idefault', '-I..', '-Idefault', '-I..', '..\\test.c', '-c', '-o', 'default\\test_1.o']
command returned "Build failed: local variable 'node' referenced before assignment"
```

Could someone help me with configuring talloc on windows?

Comment: It would appear that your Cygwin installation is somehow broken or doesn't support the POSIX headers which this Samba component requires. The configure is trying to compile a hello world program and failing. So fix that.

Comment: can you provide some more details about the POSIX headers fix?

Comment: Their names a right in the configure output (stdio.h, sys/utsname.h) etc.

Comment: And don't keep creating a tag for talloc. It isn't necessary. And your question isn't really about talloc or its APIs anyway. You have a broken CYGWIN installation that can't compile hello world. Totally different question

Comment: I have created a test program and used `stdio.h`. The program compiled well

Comment: also for the command `$ cygcheck -c cygwin` I am getting the output: `Package              Version        Status
cygwin-devel         2.3.1-1        OK`

Comment: OK it that case you are going to have to accept that there samba build system doesn't support cygwin (or at least the version or configuration you have)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101056/discussion-between-mohammad-faisal-and-talonmies).